# Check for alternating numbers and booleans in arguments

Tags: javascript, alternate

I want to be able to check the arguments object for specific alternating object types, like this:

```
number, boolean, number, boolean ==> 1, true, 2, false....etc
```

I tried this (after I turned the arguments object into an array):

```
var check = args.some ( function (val, i) {
  var type = typeof(val);
  return i % 2 == 0 ? type === 'number' : type === 'boolean';
});
```

Is it possible by using the some method?

Comment: You want to check what type the arguments are? Your code confuses me

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve in more details.

Comment: @NinaScholz I thought that `some` would stop if `false`, `every` continues..

Comment: every stops on the first `false` return value.

Comment: @NinaScholz with `some` I'm able to capture the index as to where the first falsey statements was found, can that be done with `every`?

Comment: basically you could anything with `every`, what you can do with `some`. it just the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and an array for the types.

> The `every` method executes the provided `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where `callback` returns a falsy value. If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns `false`. Otherwise, if `callback` returns a truthy value for all elements, `every` returns `true`. `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

```js
function isAlternate(v, i) {
    console.log(i, v, ['number', 'boolean'][i % 2], typeof v === ['number', 'boolean'][i % 2]);
    return typeof v === ['number', 'boolean'][i % 2];
}

console.log([1, 2, 3].every(isAlternate));
console.log([1, true, 2, false].every(isAlternate));
console.log([null, null].every(isAlternate));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```js
function check(array) {
    return array.every(function (v, i) {
        if (typeof v === ['number', 'boolean'][i % 2]) {
            return true;
        }
        console.log('wrong item found at', i);
    });
}

console.log(check([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(check([1, true, 2, false]));
console.log(check([null, null]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With ES6, you could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
function getWrongIndex(array) {
    return array.findIndex((v, i) => typeof v !== ['number', 'boolean'][i % 2]);
}

console.log(getWrongIndex([1, 2, 3]));           //  1
console.log(getWrongIndex([1, true, 2, false])); // -1 no wrong index found
console.log(getWrongIndex([null, null]));        //  0
```